# Convert HTML code to laravel(or any framework)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My question is simple and may be very basic. What is the best way to convert HTML pages to Laravel.?

In HTML pages the links are like `<a href="about-us.html">`,
 we have to convert it to `<a href="{{ URL::asset('about-us.html')}}">` for Laravel.

Now i am manually editing entire HTML code to achieve it. Is there any short way to do it.?(i used replace all in CodeIgniter) Or What is the best way to avoid this overwork? Any other workflow between designer and programmer?

Note: Please comment here if you dont understand this question well. I will edit it.:)

Comment: There is no reason to do that. Your HTML pages should work even without Laravel generating the URLs. The only benefit you get from changing them is that it will use Laravel's routing system, but since your HTML pages are just that and served to the client, all you need to make sure is that the assets are retrievable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way is,

1. Copy all HTML files, and paste them into the **view** folder.
2. Change all files extensions from .html to .blade.php (eg. `about.html` to `about.blade.php`).
3. Remove the '.html' from all anchors href, so `<a href='about.html'>` will be  `<a href='about'>`. (Just replace .html with "" ).
4. Copy all other files/folders (js folder, CSS folder, image folder, etc) from the root folder to the public folder.
5. Create a route for your static pages.
   You can create a route for each page or you can create a single common route for all pages, like this.

   ```
    Route::get('{page_name}', function($page_name)
    {
        //
        return View::make('frontend/'.$page_name);
    });
   ```

- It will take only 5 minutes to convert a complete 5-page static website.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this without editing each and every page.

Laravel is based on `Routing`. So you can't convert your link to,

```
<a href="{{ URL::asset('about-us.html')}}">
```

Note the `about-us.html`. Instead of this you should do this,

First make a `Route` in `app/routes.php`

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('about');
});
```

Then save your `about-us.html` file as `about.blade.php` in `app/views`.

And you can make the link like this,

```
{{ HTML::link('about', 'About Us') }}
```

For better html conversion, see the `HTMLBuilder API` [here](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Html.HtmlBuilder.html).